# How to move tick marks above the x-axis in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am working on a chart in Chart.js and my x-axis looks like this:
[image]

I have already looked into documentation and GitHub and it doesn't seem possible to realign the far left label to the right and the far right label to the left a little. However, I am wondering if it is possible to have the tick marks going up from the x-axis instead of down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible in Chart.js as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`mirror`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.0/axes/cartesian/category.html#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes) option in the ticks like so:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderWidth: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        ticks: {
          mirror: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi. I want the tick marks themselves to be pointing above the x-axis. Not the tick mark labels.